# In Visual Studio web performance test Recording is started but script is not generated? why?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012, testing, web

I'm using visual studio 2010. i'm try to do web performance test. so i've done all settings correctly. click the start recording button. that time browser was automatically opened with that particular webpage. i do some actions. but that actions scripts are not generated in in my visual studio web test. last two months ago i worked this test successfully. but now i can't get it. so please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what kinda of API requests you want to record. For HTTP request from Internet Explorer, you should be able to record everything with Visual Studio; but for HTTPS requests or requests from other browsers other than , Fiddler is a definitely better tool to record requests instead of using only Visual Studio. This doc may be helpful to you for using Fiddler:
http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/creating-a-web-performance-test-using-fiddler/
and 
http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler